# sha256 hash password in db adds extra backslashes when I retrieve it from database - psycopg2/python

Tags: python, postgresql, hash, comparison, psycopg2

I am currently hashing a user email address and comparing the hash with the email address hashes stored in postgres.

The hashes stored in postgres return extra backslashes for the hashed string when I execute query from python.

```
query = "SELECT email_addr_hash FROM TABLE WHERE email_addr_hash_in_db = %s::character varying"
cur.execute(query,(input_addr_hash,))
result = cur.fetchall()
```

The query does not return anything cos the hash from db that I retrieve looks like this:

```
[('s$O+\\x1d\\xd0\\xac8\\xccU\\xeeW^2|\\\\{\\x0bS.G}h\\xf0S\\x0f\\xbd\\xd4\\xda\\xfc\\x00\\x88',)]
```

The hash in python to compare :

```
b's$O+\x1d\xd0\xac8\xccU\xeeW^2|\\{\x0bS.G}h\xf0S\x0f\xbd\xd4\xda\xfc\x00\x88'
```

Please guide me if I am doing the comparison right and how to get rid of off backslashes

Comment: The extra slashes from the database are for escaping because backslash is a reserved character in that database. Although it looks like you're storing the raw bytes of the hash in the database. If you have control over it, you should decode the raw bytes using a method like  `.decode('utf-8)`

Comment: @Jamalan The backslash is *not* a special character in SQL. Perhaps `standard_conforming_strings = off`.

Comment: What does the hash look like in the database, that is you do `SELECT email_addr_hash FROM TABLE` directly in psql (no python or other apps that might transform the response)?

Comment: If the query doesn't return anything, where did that thing you showed us come from?  Please show the code that obtained and printed that.

Comment: Oh then yeah check and see what it looks like in the database, it might be escaping it when you retrieve it from the cursor. But regardless main point is that you have raw bytes there you should change it to an actual encoded hash

Comment: If I run this query directly on database, It shows the proper string without adding extra backslashes. Its escaping when I retrieve it from cursor.

Comment: standard_conforming_strings = on worked. Thank you.